# How to update a field's value?

Tags: 7, entities

Like the `field_get_items` function, is there a function to update a field's value? I want to update a field of type *user reference*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example I load a node and change the value of a field called `field_context` and then saves the updated node:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->field_context[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'foo';
node_save($node);
```

Use `var_dump` to show what fields your node contains.

Comment: hmm, begs the question why is this allowed to *set* the field but not to [*get* the field](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way)

Comment: No, actually it *raises* the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your node, change it, and save it with `node_save($node)`.

Answer (score 1):

Although the accepted answer works fine but a new and easier way is to use Entity API and its wrapper classes. You can find more info about Entity Metadata Wrappers [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). Here is how the code would look like

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
$node_wrapper->field_custom_field = 'foo';
$node_wrapper->save();
```

The wrapper will take care of validating your data as well.